# How to separate price(number) from a web scraped mixed string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get the price of a url that I provide as an input.

```py
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import time
    from smtplib import SMTP
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import requests

    URL='https://www.bigbasket.com/pd/10000200/fresho-tomato-hybrid-1-kg/?nc=cl-prod-list&t_pg=&t_p=&t_s=cl-prod-list&t_pos=1&t_ch=desktop'

    headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36 OPR/65.0.3467.78'}

    page= requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')


    div=soup.find(id="price")
    print(div)
```

I am trying to get the price: 37.50 as the output. 
This is the output I am getting:

```html
    <div id="price">
    <table><tbody class="_6eiYL" id="10000200">
            <tr class="_23Nyv">
                <td>MRP: </td><td class="_2ifWF">Rs <!-- -->37.50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="_157dw">
                <td> <!-- -->Price:</td><td class="IyLvo" data-qa="productPrice">Rs <!-- -->30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="_21awm">
                <td>You Save: </td>
                <td class="IyLvo">20%</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
    <td></td> 
    <td>(Inclusive of all taxes)</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? I’m voting to close this, as it stands it looks like you would benefit more from a guide or tutorial than from Stack Overflow, and I can’t see this question being of any use to anyone else.

Comment: im trying to develop a code which compares prices for a given keyword between 2 websites,the code which ive written above just gets me the price of the keyword,which i was unable to fetch,i think this might be useful to people who are new to python including myself

Comment: Sorry if I wasn’t clear, my point is that “How to parse HTML” is too broad of a topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the price that you're grabbing (of 37.50) is the MRP, not the price given by the site, which is Rs 30.

```
<td class="IyLvo" data-qa="productPrice">Rs <!-- -->30</td>
```

I'd expect you're actually interested in that price as opposed to the MRP.

Here's code that grabs both and extracts the numeric values without relying on regex. (Regular expressions would be more robust.) I chose CSS selectors that are more intuitively readable than using the letter-salad classes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL='https://www.bigbasket.com/pd/10000200/fresho-tomato-hybrid-1-kg/?nc=cl-prod-list&t_pg=&t_p=&t_s=cl-prod-list&t_pos=1&t_ch=desktop'

headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36 OPR/65.0.3467.78'}

page= requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

# Here are sample ways to select the proper elements
mrp_string = soup.select_one('#price tr').text
actual_price_string = soup.select_one('td[data-qa="productPrice"]').text

# various ways to go from "MRP: Rs 37.50" to a numeric, here's one
mrp = float(mrp_string.replace("MRP: Rs ",""))

# various ways to go from the price string "Rs 30" to a numeric, here's one
actual_price = float(actual_price_string.replace("Rs ",""))

print("MRP: Rs", mrp)
print("Price: Rs", actual_price)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `regex re`. Find the div element then find the `MRP:` text inside `td` tag and then get the next `td` tag contents.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

URL='https://www.bigbasket.com/pd/10000200/fresho-tomato-hybrid-1-kg/?nc=cl-prod-list&t_pg=&t_p=&t_s=cl-prod-list&t_pos=1&t_ch=desktop'

headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36 OPR/65.0.3467.78'}

page= requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

item=soup.find('div',id="price").find_next('td', text=re.compile('MRP:')).find_next('td').contents
print(item[-1])
```

Comment: This is much slicker, nice one.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.bigbasket.com/pd/10000200/fresho-tomato-hybrid-1-kg/?nc=cl-prod-list&t_pg=&t_p=&t_s=cl-prod-list&t_pos=1&t_ch=desktop")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.findAll("td", {'class': '_2ifWF'}):
    print(item.text[3:])
```

Output:

```
36.25
```